# actualizar dos input date de manera automatica?

Tags: php, html, date, entrada

Necesito realizar que al momento de crear 2 input, cuando seleccione la fecha del primero, el segundo no se pueda seleccionar de la fecha de mas atras.

esto es lo poco que llevo

```
<table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Fecha de inicio</th>
                    <th>Fecha de termino</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th><input type="date" name="dateInicio" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" min="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>"/></th>
                    <th><input type="date" name="dateInicio" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" min="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>"/></th>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vas por buen camino. Puedes hacerlo con javascript.

Intenta:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Fecha de inicio</th>
    <th>Fecha de termino</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="date" name="dateInicio" id="dateInicio" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" min="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" onchange="handler(event);"/></td>
    <td><input type="date" name="dateTermino" id="dateTermino" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" min="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>"/></td>
</tr>
</table>

<script>
function handler(e){
    document.getElementById('dateTermino').value = e.target.value; // actualiza el valor actual
    document.getElementById('dateTermino').min = e.target.value; // setea el nuevo minimo
}
</script>
```

Usamos el evento `onchange` del input dateInicio para llamar a la función `handler` la cual realiza lo que tu quieres..